# View WYSIWYG Content

Tags: html, wysiwyg

I am sure this is a very basic question. I'm using a WYSIWYG editor to enter content and save it to the database. When I load that content to the web page, it shows as plain text and the browser doesn't render the html tags correctly. It just shows up as

```
<p>This is some text</p>
```

This is my first interaction with a WYSIWYG editor. Thanks for your help!

Comment: which code did u use to display content in the page..?
Can u put that code which you use to load into webpage into this..?

Comment: PHP...Laravel framework.

Comment: Bro..use `<?php echo $vari; ?>` do not use `{{ $vari }}`.Laravel put only plain text.Blade do not support that.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Works, thanks. Feel free to post answer and I'll give credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP :

```
{{ $data }}
```

Use :

```
<?php echo $data ?>
```